# Android proguard crashed when Azure mobile app is used

Tags: android, azure, mobile, proguard

I use [Azure mobile app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop/) in my new Android project.
When I run the app on debug mode, the Mobile app works successfully and I can see my new records in my table.

My problem is starting when I creates an apk file with proguard.
I am sorry to say that I am newbie on Proguard then I can not solve my Proguard problems even I read the documentation at offical Proguard page.

So, I get these errors when I try to create apk file with Proguard without any Proguard code.

```
Warning: com.google.common.base.Absent: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning: com.google.common.base.Absent: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning: com.google.common.base.Ascii: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning: com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$StringConverter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
```

and more hundreads line...

```
Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning: com.google.common.cache.Striped64$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
```

and more hundreads line....

```
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
```

Then I added these line in my proguard.

```
-keep class okio.** { *; }
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**

-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.inject.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

-keep class com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.os.**
-dontwarn com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.RequestAsyncTask
```

After that, Android studio created the apk however The app crahsed as soon as It started. Then I investigate the logs, I saw new warnings that color are white.

```
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslError]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.HttpResponseCache]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate$DName]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]
Note: there were 11 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

@MustafaOlkun, It seems that the solutions for your issues can be found at the [troubleshooting](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html) page of ProGuard.

For the issue `Warning: can't find referenced class`, please see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass.

For the issue `Note: duplicate definition of library class`, please see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for advance, After I add Fabric crahslatics tool, I saw where my app crashed and I understand that I must add new -keep and -keepclassmembers lines for my some java files that are implements from Serializeble.